# Action is not defined as a method in the component vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to access an action as a method in component, But got error of

> this.delete_notifaction is not a function

**notifaction.js**

```
export const actions = {
  add_notifaction({ commit }, notifaction) {
   commit("ADD_NOTIFACTION", notifaction);
  },
  delete_notifaction({ commit }, notificationToRemove) {
   commit('DELETE_NOTIFACTION', notificationToRemove)
  }
};
```

**store/index.js**

```
modules : {
  notifaction
},
```

**Component.vue**

```
methods: mapActions('notifaction',["delete_notifaction"]),
mounted() {
   this.delete_notifaction(this.notification);
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Could you check that you only have one `methods` section on your component definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
methods: {
   ...mapActions(['delete_notifaction']),
}
```

See here for spread syntax
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137766/10118668